# UIimage didn't fully received by the server xcode

Tags: ios

I have this code I want to send image to server using Tcp socket:

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"J-Eje_Ambiental.png"];
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString *encodedString = [imgData base64Encoding];

NSLog(@"image code : %@",encodedString);

NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ing:%@",encodedString];
    NSLog(@"image code : %@",response);
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```

when i print the bas64string in xcode it have hundreds of lines
but on the server I have only 19 line 
I dont receive all the image data ...

please help !!

Comment: Would need to see server code.

Answer (score 1):

Images usually have this amount of lines ,Check the encoding used. `NSUTF8StringEncoding` gives you pretty big output,May be the serverside used some other encoding to save the data Set up an imageview and set the image with this data and check weather it gives right or wrong

Comment: i have the right data of the image ,but when i send it ,it send only 19 lines